# How to stop the main thread and wait until an opened popup form disposes in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, popup

I have 2 classes: `control` and `popup`. I run a loop to and call 3 jframe forms.
I want on the main control class, it must stop and wait until a popup disposes before continue the loop and open another one. How can I achieve this?

I tried to create add an `extraThread` to run the popup and use `extraThread.join()` but it still doesn't work.

**control**

```
package main;

public class control {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            popup pop = new popup();
            System.out.println("" + i);
            pop.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**popup**

```
package main;

import java.awt.SystemColor;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class popup {

    private JFrame frmpopup;

    public popup() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmpopup = new JFrame();
        frmpopup.getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
        frmpopup.setTitle("Standard Form");
        frmpopup.setBounds(100, 100, 224, 269);
        frmpopup.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void show() {
        frmpopup.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a modal dialog - see [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your suggestion. That's a great idea. But I'm wondering if there is a possible solution for JFrame here?

Comment: The short answer is no, because that's not what frames are designed to do, the dialog basically takes over the posting of events from the EDT, allowing to continue blocking until it is disposed. The process by which this is achieved is not simple and not pretty

Comment: If, for some bizarre reason you HAVE to do this, then you want to take a look at [Foxtrot](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/), which is a lot of fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using in-build method for Jframe to know its status. 
You could do something like this.

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            popup pop = new popup();
            System.out.println("" + i);
            pop.show();
            while (pop.isDisplayed()) {
                // waiting
                Thread.sleep(1000);   // you could remove this as well
            }
        }
    }
}
```

popup class

```
class popup {

    private JFrame frmpopup;

    public popup() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmpopup = new JFrame();
        frmpopup.getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
        frmpopup.setTitle("Standard Form");
        frmpopup.setBounds(100, 100, 224, 269);
        frmpopup.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void show() {
        frmpopup.setVisible(true);
    }

    public boolean isDisplayed() {
        if (frmpopup.isDisplayable())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```